# Unable to connect Hbase remotely by java code

Tags: java

I have installed HBase on Linux Machine(192.168.1.000) and now I have written some sample Code in Eclipse IDE on same linux Machine using JAVA API to communicate with HBase and it's working fine but when I written same java code on windows machine in same version of Ecliple IDE to communicate with HBase on Linux Machine(192.168.1.000). I got:

```
14/12/02 15:42:40 INFO client.ZooKeeperSaslClient: Client will not SASL-authenticate because the            default JAAS configuration section 'Client' could not be found. If you are not using SASL, you may     ignore this. On the other hand, if you expected SASL to work, please fix your JAAS configuration.
14/12/02 15:42:40 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,     closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:286)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1035)
14/12/02 15:42:40 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper exception:     org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for    /hbase/master
14/12/02 15:42:40 INFO util.RetryCounter: The 1 times to retry  after sleeping 2000 ms
```

whereas my code is:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.clear();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.1.000");
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.1.000:60030");
HBaseAdmin hbAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(config);`enter code here`
```

Please help me to get out from here:

Thanks in advance
Abhinav kumar

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct IP address ?

Answer (score 0):

BindException from your stacktrace is when you try to run your hbase, it will start a co-ordinator service on port 2181 i.e. zookeeper but as the port might already been in use by some other process, it throws BindException.

Change the port and retry.

Comment: Thanks almas shaikh for your suggestion i do as you say but i got new exception:   Unknown Host  ip6-192.168.1.12 where as my usr/hosts having configuration 192.168.1.12 localhost hbase
192.168.1.12 ngi-Satellite-Pro-B40-A

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-192.168.1.12 ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters  as  192.168.1.12 is the ip of where hbase is installed.